# React tinymce troubles with setting variable to content parameter

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

I'm experiencing problems with setting up `npm react tinymce`. Version `3.10.10`.
The problem is that after I installed package and added my component there is a parameter called `content` in which I should insert my data. And somehow it takes only a string value. If I'm trying to set it to a variable or expression it does nothing and there is no errors in console. Did anyone experienced same problem before? Here is short example of how I'm trying to set my component:

```
<TinyMCE
  content = {this.state.text}
            onChange={this.handleEditorChange}
/>
```

In that case it shows blanked editor.
And here is example of how it works correctly:

```
<TinyMCE
 content = 'Any string will display the text correctly'
            onChange={this.handleEditorChange}
/>
```

Comment: I have tested `react-tinymce` from `npm`. It works properly with literal string or with any string variable. Are you sure your passed `content` argument is a string or any format used by `tinymce` ?

Comment: @Firice Nguyen thanks for respond. I'm hundred percent sure. The only difference in this two cases is that I'm setting variable with string content and it doesn't seems to work. Here is an example of not working code:
`let test = 'Just a regular string';
<TinyMCE
  content = {test}
            onChange={this.handleEditorChange}
/>`
Apologeese for not formatted code. I just dont know how to write it nicely.

Comment: It would be great if you can take a picture of your `tinymce` editor. I am wondering if you set it up correctly. Have you tried to use `tiny-mce4` ?

Comment: https://github.com/instructure-react/react-tinymce#dependency May be you can try to include latest `tinymce` using this link

Comment: I didn't hear about `tiny-mce4`. Will also try it. Thanks. Look, I was setting up tinymce regarding this link: [react-tinymce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tinymce).
I imported modules to my component, than I added a `handleEditorChange` method to the same component, than I installed packages and saved it to dev dependencies to my json file. And last thing I also added this script `<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.2/tinymce.min.js"></script>` to exceptions for webpack in purpose it won't be deleted during build. Maybe you can tell me more specific which information you also need.

Comment: Thanks @Firice Nguyen I will try your advices

Comment: In this example: https://github.com/instructure-react/react-tinymce/blob/master/examples/basic/app.js , they are setting the contents using variable too. So that the reason seems to be your setup. How do you add the `tinymce` into your application?

Comment: @Firice Nguyen I'm using npm install, adding it to dev dependency and importing into a component where I'm using it

Comment: Can you try add `<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.2/tinymce.min.js"></script>` into `index.html` or whenever you render `react` ?

Comment: Yes I already did it. Without that script I'm getting console error that tinymce is not defined

Comment: Is it possible to experience this problem due to different versions of tiny, react or anything else ?

Comment: It would be great if you can upload your code into github or somewhere else that I can have a look.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot because it's a commercial project so I'm not allowed to :(

Comment: If your `tinymce` view looks like this: http://instructure-react.github.io/react-tinymce/basic/ . Then you should set it up correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come to the same problem and finally figured out what it was. The value passed to the component is the original value. Once received, the component will take over and handle the content state, regardless of whether a new value is passed to it. So if you are passing a string, then it's a constant and it exists at initial render of your component. But if you are passing a variable, it's possible that the initial value of the variable is different to the value you want to display (like it's probably null or undefined until your component receives the value to display). In my case I receive an object with the page contents, one of which is the html to display as initial content. But the render method was first being fired with an empty object, and then with the actual object with data. What I did to fix this is set a key to my tiny mce wrapper, with the value of my object's id.

```
<TinyMCE
    key={customPageData.id} // this line made the trick
    content={customPageData.body}
    config={{
        plugins: "link image lists print preview",
        toolbar:
            "undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist",
    }}
    onChange={handleEditorChange}
/>
```

Comment: great @Messiah! Do accept the answer as correct then!

Comment: It's easy to forget to use key prop for a single component. Thanks you for reminding me of that.